# WPF,is there a smart way of replaceing element of Grid?

Tags: wpf

> Grid had been added element by Row and Column,i want to add new element to grid by follow way:

```
grid.children[i] =element as UieElement;
```

It is invaild to me.have a error.

I am avoiding refresh in thread,so i have not clear Grid.Children.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
grid.Children.RemoveAt(i);
grid.Children.Insert(i, element as UieElement);
```

(also, but I think it as a typo : Children should be capital C in grid.Children ...)

Answer (score 0):

To add elements, this is how you would have to do it:

```
grid.Children.Add(element);
```

If you want to set the row/column, you can set the properties programmatically before adding it, like so:

```
element.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
```

You can access an existing portion by index like in your example if you just need to access a specific child.

Comment: I want to replace specific child,then add to this position.

Comment: grid.children[i] =element as UieElement; this way genetate error.

Comment: grid.childer.Clear() is not method that i want to use.